# How can I test my asynchronous code in a restify HTTP handler?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sinon, chai, restify

I have a function in my Restify project that handles an HTTP GET request. After some processing it uses Sequelize to find the user entity for my current session. The `User.findOne` function returns a promise and depending on the result of that promise, I'm sending an HTTP response with 200 or 404.

```
static getMe(req, res, next) {
    const userInfo = BaseController.getUserSession(req);

    // hard to test this part
    User.findOne({
      where: {email: userInfo.email}
    }).then(function(user) {
      if (user) BaseController.respondWith200(res, user);
      else BaseController.respondWith404(res, 'User not found.');
    }, function(error) {
      BaseController.respondWith404(res, error);
    }).then(function() {
      return next();
    });
}
```

I've tried a few different libraries to help with testing so I'm sorry if this is a messy combination of things. This is in my `beforeEach` function for my tests:

```
const usersFixture = [
  {id:2, email:'ozzy@osbourne.com', facebookId:54321, displayName: 'Ozzy Osbourne'},
  {id:3, email:'zakk@wylde.com', facebookId:34521, displayName: 'Zakk Wylde'},
  {id:4, email:'john@lennon.com', facebookId:12453, displayName: 'John Lennon'}
];

this.findOneSpy = sinon.spy(function(queryObj) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const user = usersFixture.find(function(el) { return el.email === queryObj.where.email });
    if (user) resolve(user);
    else resolve(null);
  });
});

this.respondWith200Spy = sinon.spy(function(res, data) {});
this.respondWith400Spy = sinon.spy(function(res, error) {});
this.respondWith404Spy = sinon.spy(function(res, error) {});

this.controller = proxyquire('../../controllers/user-controller', {
  '../models/user': {
    findOne: this.findOneSpy
  },
  './base-controller': {
    respondWith200: this.respondWith200Spy,
    respondWith400: this.respondWith400Spy,
    respondWith404: this.respondWith404Spy
  }
});
```

And here is what one of my tests looks like:

```
it('should return 200 with user data if user email matches existing user', function() {
  // THIS FUNCTION IS NEVER HIT
  this.respondWith200Spy = function(res, data) {
    data.should.equal({id:4, email:'john@lennon.com', facebookId:12453, displayName: 'John Lennon'});
    done();
  };
  const req = {session:{user:{email:'john@lennon.com'}}};
  this.controller.getMe(req, this.res, this.nextSpy);
  this.findOneSpy.should.have.been.called;
});
```

Since we aren't actually passing a callback to the function and the function doesn't really return anything (just does asynchronous things elsewhere), I can't figure out how to test it to make sure it's working right. Any help is appreciated.

The actual code works just fine. I'm just trying to get some quality unit testing into the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to do it using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire). I just re-stubbed the controller class that I am testing and made the `respondWith200` callback make an assertion. Then I created a new spy for the `next` function that just calls `done` (which is passed into the test case). I verified that the code is all getting hit.

```
it('should return 200 with user data if user email matches existing user', function(done) {
  const controller = proxyquire('../../controllers/user-controller', {
    '../models/user': {
      findOne: this.findOneSpy
    },
    './base-controller': {
      respondWith200: function(res, data) {
        data.displayName.should.equal('John Lennon');
      },
      respondWith400: this.respondWith400Spy,
      respondWith404: this.respondWith404Spy
    }
  });
  const req = {grft_session:{user:{email:'john@lennon.com'}}};
  const nextSpy = sinon.spy(function() {
    done();
  });
  controller.getMe(req, this.res, nextSpy);
  this.findOneSpy.should.have.been.called;
});
```